# Wordpress (Grow Pro): How to change primary header menu in header.php

Tags: wordpress, menu

I just started taking care of an already existing website and installed the max mega menu plugin to have more control over the menu buttons. However, on mobile devices the original menu toggle is still visible but not responsive.

So I deactivated the plugin again but the menu toggle remains unresponsive which means that right now the site has either no working menu or two menu toggles on mobile devices.

```
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up until id="main-core".
 *
 * @package ThinkUpThemes
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<?php thinkup_hook_header(); ?>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="profile" href="//gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php esc_url( bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ) ); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?><?php thinkup_bodystyle(); ?>>
<?php /* Body hook */ thinkup_hook_bodyhtml(); ?>
<?php /* Notification Bar */ thinkup_input_notification(); ?>
<?php /* Header Image */ thinkup_input_headerimage(); ?>
<div id="body-core" class="hfeed site">

    <header>
    <div id="site-header">

        <?php  if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
            <div class="custom-header"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->width ); ?>" height="<?php echo esc_attr( get_custom_header()->height ); ?>" alt=""></div>
        <?php endif; // End header image check. ?>

        <div id="pre-header">
        <div class="wrap-safari">
        <div id="pre-header-core" class="main-navigation">

             <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'pre_header_menu' ) ) : ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'header-links', 'container_id' => 'pre-header-links-inner', 'theme_location' => 'pre_header_menu' ) ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 

            <?php /* Pre Header Search */ thinkup_input_preheadersearch(); ?>

            <?php /* Social Media Icons */ thinkup_input_socialmediaheaderpre(); ?>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #pre-header -->

        <?php /* Add header - above slider */ thinkup_input_headerlocationabove(); ?>

        <?php /* Add responsive header menu */ thinkup_input_responsivehtml2_above(); ?>

        <?php /* Add sticky header */ thinkup_input_headersticky(); ?>

        <?php /* Custom Slider */ thinkup_input_sliderhome(); ?>

        <?php /* Custom Intro - Above */ thinkup_custom_introabove(); ?>

        <?php /* Custom Slider */ thinkup_input_sliderpage(); ?>

        <?php /* Add header - above slider */ thinkup_input_headerlocationbelow(); ?>

        <?php /* Add responsive header menu */ thinkup_input_responsivehtml2_below(); ?>

        <?php /* Custom Intro - Below */ thinkup_custom_introbelow(); ?>

    </div>


    </header>
    <!-- header -->

    <?php /*  Call To Action - Intro */ thinkup_input_ctaintro(); ?>
    <?php /*  Pre-Designed HomePage Content */ thinkup_input_homepagesection(); ?>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="content-core">

        <div id="main">
        <div id="main-core">
```

The theme lets me choose between three menu positions: Pre header, primary header and footer. I looked into the header.php and found it strange that I could not find any code about the primary header menu. Please note that I am an absolute newbie to website hosting and css programming!!

How can I remove the 'old' menu toggle from the website and/or make it responsive again?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the main menu of a wordpress, from the admin page /wp-admin/nav-menus.php, at the bottom it has a checkbox to indicate as Primary menu.

Your theme's header.php has the default function to display the wordpress primary menu:

```php
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'header-links', 'container_id' => 'pre-header-links-inner', 'theme_location' => 'pre_header_menu' ) ); ?>
```

You can check the [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) the `wp_nav_menu()` wordpress function.

Alternatively you can change your header.php the obove line to:

```php
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => $the_id_of_your_menu,'container_class' => 'header-links', 'container_id' => 'pre-header-links-inner', 'theme_location' => 'pre_header_menu' ) ); ?>
```

You can find the `$the_id_of_your_menu` by visiting your menu in the wp-admin and clicking the `select` button as described [here](https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/find-menu-id-wordpress/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think, I didn't explain my problem very well. I already have the right menu in the right position. However, I think that my problem is actually consisting of two problems: 1.) The menu toggle is not working when I open the website on a mobile device. 2.) After installing the max mega menu plugin I see two menu toggles. The one from the plugin that is working perfectly well and the original, broken, one.